# extract text between 2 strings only till first occurence of end string

Tags: linux, perl, shell, aix

I am trying to extract string between device_uuid: and the immediate ,

d

```
device_uuid:xxx,yyy,ttt
device_uuid:2,ppp,hhh
```

code:

```
$ sed -e 's/device_uuid:\(.*\),/\1/' d
xxx,yyyttt
2,ppphhh
```

expected o/p:

```
xxx
2
```

Edit 1:

cant use grep -oP as i am on AIX

using awk fails :

d

```
device_uuid:xxx,yyy,ttt
ptr,ttt
device_uuid:2,ppp,hhh
total_uuid:5,jkl,mno
device_uuid:9

$ awk -F 'total_uuid:|,' '{print $2}' d
yyy
ttt
ppp
5
```

expected o/p in above case:

```
blank or device_uuid:xxx,yyy,ttt
blank or ptr,ttt
blank or device_uuid:2,ppp,hhh
5
blank or device_uuid:9
```

device_uuid: need not be the first column , like wise all can be random but i need to pick that variable corresponding vale until the immediate delimiter ,

-- Cut also fails as it can only accept one char delimiter .

-- `$ perl -l -ne '/device_uuid:([\w\-]*?)\,/g and print($1)' d`

above perl also fails because ,if the device_uuid is not present in a line then that line is deleted in the o/p , but it should be
displayed as blank

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `sed`:**

```
sed 's/^.*total_uuid:\([^,]*\).*$/\1/' file
device_uuid:xxx,yyy,ttt
ptr,ttt
device_uuid:2,ppp,hhh
5
device_uuid:9
```

**Using `grep -oP`:**

```
grep -oP 'device_uuid:\K[^,]+' file
xxx
2
```

Comment: how to use -oP in AIX  ? it doesnt support those options ?

Comment: Well you didn't mention AIX in question. Anyway you can use my awk command.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but a couple of `cut`s should do the job:

```
$ echo "device_uuid:xxx,yyy,ttt" | cut -d":" -f2- | cut -d"," -f1
xxx
```

Comment: $ echo "device_uuid:xxx,yyy,ttt" | cut -d"device_uuid:" -f2- | cut -d"," -f1
evice_uuid:xxx       --                i cant delimit alone on :